# How to know if app user is offline?

Tags: android, ios, iphone

My chat app has the following approach:

- When user logs in on App, his status changes to Online. "Status = 1"
- When user logs out of App, his status changes to Offline "Last Available". "Status = 0"

The idea is that when logged user disconnects from internet, his status remains 1. Also if user removes the app his status remains 1.

Is there a code or way to detect when user was last online after removing/deleting app? Many users who removed the App still have their status as Online.

Answer (score 2):

You basically have to keep track of when they last accessed your server.  If the last access was more than X minutes ago (X is something you decide), then you put them as offline.

Comment: Is there a way to show users Online if app is running in background?

Comment: Yes it will.  If they're accessing the server, their last access time gets updates.  That will keep them online.  If their last access time is too old, you show them as offline.  As for actively using the app vs background-  you can differentiate between a user initiated request and an automatic request in your service api, which would give you enough info to tell.

Comment: So detect if user is online and app is opened in background, I send an automatic request every few mins? Any example to check?

Answer (score 2):

Inside your Activity , `onStart()` and `onResume()`, you can send the online presence message to the server as:

- **1** (means online)
- **0** (means offline) respectively,

But the problem is **what will happen if the app comes to foreground or if internet stops or if user uninstall the app ?**

Your server will still have the last presence as online only. One way to solve it is using [MQTT](https://eclipse.org/paho/clients/java/org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3).

In `Activity`, `onStart()` and `onResume()`, send the online presence message to the broker as 1, 0 respectively. While making the mqtt connection, set the last will message:

```
 MqttConnectOptions options = new MqttConnectOptions();
                options.setConnectionTimeout(60);
                options.setWill(STATUS, ("PASS_OFFLINE_STATUS_OF_USER").getBytes(), 0, true);
                client.setCallback(ApplozicMqttService.this);

                client.connect(options);
```

> **Source:** https://github.com/AppLozic/Applozic-Android-SDK/blob/b7337f8d43c9e4df8927c77b34903c7762670cbf/mobicomkit/src/main/java/com/applozic/mobicomkit/api/ApplozicMqttService.java

Last will message is used in MQTT to notify other clients about an ungracefully disconnected client.

**Read more here:**

> http://www.hivemq.com/blog/mqtt-essentials-part-9-last-will-and-testament