# How to check/access a different activity's lifecycle from the current activity?

Tags: java, android, android-activity, firebase-realtime-database

I want to access the activity lifecycle method of a different activity from the present one... Can i do that? for example i have 2 activities A and B. I want to access the onStop method of activity A from activity B. can i do that? i'm trying to check the online of a user in my app which has multiple activities so i want to write code which is like = If onStop/onDestroy method of both the activities are called show that the user is offline... The code im using is

```
        @Override
    public void onStart(){
    super.onStart();
    mDatabaseReference.child("Online").setValue(true);
    }

        @Override
    public void onStop(){
    super.onStop();
    mDatabaseReference.child("Online").setValue(false);
}
```

Can someone please help me out

Comment: You probably can use some ugly workaround to do that, but Android Architecture is designed the way that you should not access one activity from other. Correct way will be to refactor your app's arcitecture

Comment: Or you can use callbacks.

Comment: You can create separate singleton class and save the state of activities there. Then you can access the state of the saved states of activities in other activities.

Comment: You cannot do that, If you want to check the availability of the user there are other ways to do it.

Comment: can i know what the other ways are @Umair
How do i achieve this using callbacks

Comment: @EmiliaJames easy way is to put a flag in your logic. So if any user goes offline you send the flag to server using web service. Take a look at this question for further assistance. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35947316/how-to-know-if-app-user-is-offline

And other way is to use broadcast receivers. You can use callbacks too if you can tell me what type of callbacks you want to use that will help :)

Comment: Can i get the complete code of it please and where to type it? because i have never worked with these and have no clue about its working @Umair

Comment: I am sure you will find relevant code on the internet. If you can the link I posted in comment above you will know where you can type it. As far as broadcast receivers are concerned first see how do we use receivers and for call back you got the answer below follow the links and you will be good.

Comment: You can simply use application class for your requirement

Comment: Its better to use sharedPreferences to set the value.

Answer (score 0):

Use [Application.ActivityLifecycleCallbacks](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Application.ActivityLifecycleCallbacks) in your Application class. This way you just need to register your activities to the callbacks and from the application class only you can track down wheather any activity is present or not.

For more info please refer to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14470360/9734616)

Comment: Isn't there a simpler solution? because that answer looks too complicated

Comment: @EmiliaJames please follow https://gist.github.com/alexjlockwood/6298122 for simplest implementation.

Answer (score 0):

To set the value You can use [SharedPreferences](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences). Declare the instance of sharedpreference at application level.

In Activity A and B you can set the value in onStop(), onDestroy() and onStart() block.

Comment: can i get the code on how to achieve that please... i have never worked on sharedpreferences before for this purpose